# How do I use Python to check if the first letter of a string is within a certain range?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a novice with python and I'm asking how to get python to detect if a variable begins with a group of letters. Like A-L.

So far I have this:

```
import time
import os
title = input("Hello! What is your title? (As in Miss Mr etc) ")
name = input("Okay! Now what is your name? ")
sname = input("Okay, now what is your surname? ")
print("Okay, now what is your date of birth?")
dob = input("Type it like this: 26.9.00: ")
email = input("Okay! Please type in your E-mail: ")
phonenum = input("One last thing now! Please type in your phone number: ")
if name in range(A, L):
    print("This works!")
else:
    print("This doesn't work...")
```

This doesn't work though.

Comment: `if name[0] in 'ABCDEFGHIJKL':`? `range` is for integers, it's half open (exclusive of the upper bound) and `A` and `L` without quotes are identifiers, so there's no reason you should ever have *expected* that to work.

Comment: Please edit the title so it makes sense as an English question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the first character of name, not the entire name.  One way would be to convert to integer representations of characters:

```
if ord(name[0]) in range(ord('A'), ord('M')):
```

Note that `range` does not include the last endpoint, so you need to go one letter past what you want to check.

Comment: Thank you! You just fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is ok, but overengineered, just check wheter is bigger than the smaller one and smaller than the bigger:

```
if 'A' <= name[x] <= 'M':
```